# Search and filter redirecting to 404 page in Custom Product grid in custom module admin form in Magento 2?

Tags: products, filter, search, product-grid, magento2.4.3.p1

I have  created a custom product grid in my custom module form successfully Like below.

[image]

Existing products are showing fine which i saved. When i want to try search for another product i am redirecting to a 404 page. This is only happens in the server. Local host 2 instances working fine. Can anyone help me any suggestion to check this and fix this issue.

Magento version 2.4.3-p1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to update the fix. It was a spelling mistake on the module name in the grid controller. My module name was `HomeTry`, but i have updated the block class as **Hometry**. My local environment was based MAC and server is Linux, Its case sensitive. Care fully handle when naming and using it in the code.

**Existing code**

```
public function execute(){
    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    return $resultRaw->setContents(
        $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
            \Ayakil\Hometry\Block\Adminhtml\HTO\Tab\Products::class,
            'hto.assignproducts'
        )->toHtml()
    );
}
```

**Fixed code**

```
public function execute(){
    $resultRaw = $this->resultRawFactory->create();
    return $resultRaw->setContents(
        $this->layoutFactory->create()->createBlock(
            \Ayakil\HomeTry\Block\Adminhtml\HTO\Tab\Products::class,
            'hto.assignproducts'
        )->toHtml()
    );
}
```